# Can I deploy Sailsjs to AppHarbor or Heroku?

Tags: heroku, appharbor, sails.js

AppHarbor supports Node using iisnode. Can I deploy my Sails.js app to AppHarbor at this time, and if so, how?

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing with a node deploy but I'm trying to follow along with what I'm reading online. When I deploy my code out to my repo and AppHarbor builds it I get the following error: The current identity (...) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### UPDATE (September 2013)
>
> There is an updated deployment guide here:
>
> https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-wiki/blob/0.9/deployment.md …
>
> @chadn posted an example Heroku deployment with Sails.js here:
>
> https://github.com/chadn/heroku-sails

**Original post**

I don't know a whole lot about Windows deployments in general, but we do have a deployment guide here:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/wiki/Guide:-Deployment

Also, I know the guys/gals at Nodejitsu and Modulus have helped out folks getting their Sails apps set up, so that might be a good place to start as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mike - I did get an account at Nodejitsu. Trying to make it happen ;)