# Deploying a Sails.js app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, deployment, heroku, web-deployment, sails.js

I have limited experience deploying Node.js apps -- how can I deploy a Sails.js app to Heroku?

I've `heroku login`ed and `heroku create`d my app already.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should check out this github repo : [heroku-sails](https://github.com/chadn/heroku-sails)
It should get you started with sailsjs on heroku

There is a discussion around this particular github repo here [on the sails.js google group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sailsjs/vgqJFr7maSY/discussion)

These are also resources that can help you get your app running :

- [Sails Deployment Guide](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/deployment.md)
- [An answer of sails.js author to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799887/can-i-deploy-sailsjs-to-appharbor-or-heroku)

Answer (score 11):

I want to prevent any confusion for those who are familiar to node deployment on heroku. There are a lot of guides to deploying node apps to heroku and a sails app is really no different. If you start a sails app by typing "node app.js" in terminal it will work. Here is the guide put out by Heroku for node apps. The only thing different is that you have a sails rather than a plain vanilla express app.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

I've used this to deploy my sails apps no problem.

Comment: this is a great point- most things that apply to Express/Node also apply to Sails.  Pretty much all the things.

Comment: What about websockets? Do they work without problems?

Comment: I'm very new to node and sails but if I understand correctly, as long as you have sails declared correctly in your dependencies (`package.json`) then heroku will install sails via `npm`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all create sails js Website or project 
then change setting in sails js project as below:

in project config->env->production

```
   //remove from comments

  onlyAllowOrigins: [

  'https://example.com',

  'https://staging.example.com',

],

   //remove from comments

    trustProxy: true,
```

then deploy on heroku