# Heroku scheduler with SailsJS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, sails.js

I have setup a nodeJS project and I'm trying to setup a heroku scheduled job. I am using the Heroku scheduler and I have setup a task in the scheduler panel with `'node myJob.js'`. The thing is, everything in that file (myJob.js) is out of the sails App context. I cannot use anything from my app (for example the waterline ORM, the open mongo connection, a service, nothing!). Am I doomed to write the scheduled job in old fashioned javascript or am I missing something?

Comment: This answer should do the trick.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205028/deploying-a-sails-js-app-to-heroku

Comment: Technically this should be flagged as a duplicate really buddy.